# Oracle query for getting desired output

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g, varchar

> ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD 
>   data1    rata1    T     Test1
>   data1    rata3    F     Test2
>   data1    rata2    T     Test1
>   data2    rata1    T     Test1
>   data2    rata3    T     Test1
>   data3    rata4    T     Test1

Have four columns of type Varchar. What i wish to determine is for each unique value of ColB(rata1, rata2 etc), find corresponding value of ColA and other two columns (ColC, ColD) where that specific value of ColA occurs 0 or 1 time. For example- For rata1, data1 and data2 occurs one time so the output would include the columns shown below in addition to other columns for other distinct values of ColB.

```
data1    rata1    T     Test1
data2    rata1    T     Test1
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendations around the same.

Comment: WHat I don't understand is why all 6 rows are not included in the result set? For `rata3` there exists only 1 row with `data1` and 1 row with `data2`, etc.

Comment: You're right however as i mentioned the above output is only part of the output.

Comment: In a question, it's good to add sample tables and **desired sample output with those sample tables**. Otherwise, everyone gets confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With MyQuery as (select ColB from MyTable group by ColB having count(ColA) <= 1) select
t.ColB, ColA, ColC, ColD from MyTable t inner join MyQuery q on t.ColB = q.ColB
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the below query will accomplish what you want.

```
With MyQuery as
(
     select ColA, ColB
       from MyTable
   group by ColA, ColB
     having count(*) <= 1
)
select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
  from MyTable t inner join MyQuery q on t.ColB = q.ColB and t.ColA = q.ColA
```

Edit to incorporate modification supplied by John C in the comments.

```
With MyQuery as
(
     select ColB
       from MyTable
   group by ColB
     having count(ColA) <= 1
)
select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
  from MyTable t inner join MyQuery q on t.ColA = q.ColA
```

---

Comment: +1 That's what I understand, too, from the question's wording.

Comment: the aggregated WITH subquery returns rows with ColB having more than 1 unique value of ColA. The table has like 250 unique values of ColB, so the result-set should be less than or equal to 250. Have modified the query as follows With MyQuery as (select ColB from MyTable group by ColB having count(ColA) <= 1) select t.ColB, t.ColA, ColC, ColD from MyTable t inner join MyQuery q on t.ColB = q.ColB

Answer (score 2):

what I understand from you question is that you want distinct values of ColB, and then want ColA,ColC and ColD corresponding to that ColB value.
If that is the case you need not confuse yourself, just do order by ColB.

so query is

```
select * from TableA o left outer join
(select distinct ColA,ColB from TableA t)
 on o.ColA = t.ColA and o.ColB = t.ColB 
group by o.ColA having count(*) <= 1
```

Comment: The ColA should only occur 0 or 1 time.